# Set font with keyreader as package option

Tags: key-value

Im developing a package an use `keyreader` to define it’s options, but I fail to set a font as an option.

```
\begin{filecontents}{myfonts.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{myfonts}

\usepackage{keyreader}

\krddefinekeys[TW]{fam}[my]{%
   cmd/font/\sffamily/;
}

\krdProcessOptions*[TW]<fam>\relax
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

% works
\newcommand{\mymacro}{xx}% [L1]
% doesn’t work
\newcommand{\mymacro}{\ttfamily}% [L2]
\usepackage[font=\mymacro]{myfonts}% [L1,2]

% doesn’t work
\usepackage[font=\ttfamily]{myfonts}% [L3]

% works
%\krdsetkeys[TW]{fam}{font=\ttfamily}% [L4]

\begin{document}
\myfont Test
\end{document}
```

I can change the font with `\setkeys` [L4] but not as a package option [L3]. In general giving macros as values work [L1] but not if theses macros are or contain font switches [L2]. How can I fix this?

If I try to set the font as option `pdflatex` hangs. In the real package I get the TeX capacity exceeds error.

---

BTW: `\krdProcessOptions` drops an error if i omit the prefix `[TW]` in all macros …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load `xkvltxp` if you want to use commands as values. See the documentation of xkeyval for details. You can see the difference if let you show the meaning of `\myfont`:

```
\usepackage{xkvltxp}
\usepackage[font=\ttfamily]{myfonts}% [L3]
\show\myfont
```

But I would avoid to define package options which need commands as values. Better move this keys to a setup command issued later.

Answer (score 3):

A possible LaTeX3 implementation, that shows also how to set a default. The options should be passed without the backslash, in order to avoid the problem already mentioned by Ulrike. Thanks to Marco Daniel and Joseph Wright for pointing to `\ProcessKeysOptions`.

### Package myfonts.sty

```
\RequirePackage{expl3,l3keys2e}
\ProvidesExplPackage {myfonts} {2012/03/05} {1}{}
\keys_define:nn { myfonts }
  {
   font .code:n    = \cs_set_eq:Nc \myfont { #1 },
   font .default:n = sffamily,
  }
\keys_set:nn { myfonts } { font }
\ProcessKeysOptions{myfonts}
```

### Sample document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[font=ttfamily]{myfonts}

\begin{document}
\myfont Test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Question: `\krdProcessOptions` drops an error if i omit the prefix [TW] in all macros.

Answer: Upgrade your version of *keyreader package*. The latest version is available at http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/entries/keyreader.html.

Question: In general giving macros as values work [L1] but not if theses macros are or contain font switches [L2]. How can I fix this?

Answer: Ulrike Fischer is right. You can stick with *xkvltxp* package but *catoptions* package also works. Both *xkvltxp* and *catoptions* can be loaded before `\documentclass`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{testpackage.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{testpackage}
\usepackage{keyreader}
\krddefinekeys{fam}[my]{%
   cmd/font/\sffamily/;
}
\krdProcessOptions*<fam>\relax
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% works:
\newcommand{\mymacro}{\ttfamily\color{red}}
\usepackage[font=\mymacro]{testpackage}
% works:
%\usepackage[font=\ttfamily]{testpackage}
% works:
%\krdsetkeys{fam}{font=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}
{\myfont Test} document.
\end{document}
```